# .NET config cheat sheet

Tags: .net, visual-studio, configuration

Does anyone know of any good references for Microsofts configuration files.  I always need to change them manually and have never found a reference for them in the Forest of msdn documentation.

Specifically in this case what is the syntax for the type attribute used to specify the type of a class. i.e.

```
<add name="a name" type="MyApp.Model.MyClass, MyApp" />
```

And if anyone from Microsoft actually reads stackoverflow.  I hate XML config files!

EDIT:

For any one else the actual msdn for config files is [Configuration File Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fk1t1t0.aspx)

Although in this case the problem I was having was due to VS Express having problems with the output directory I had changed it to from the defualt.

Comment: Configuration for what? `machine.config`? `web.config`? `app.config` or something other?

Comment: Heh! For some reason that reminds me of "Capitalism is the worst from of government, but it's better than the alternatives."

Comment: There has too be a good alternative for configuration but unfortunately I haven't found it yet either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the right format for assembly qualified typename format, I just get an exemplar one in PowerShell:

```
"Foo".GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName
```

which returns

```
System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

For the rest of the standard `.config` and `web.config` I use the *[General Reference for the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxe8hcf2.aspx)* section on MSDN.